# How to check the current view mode of a fromview in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I want to check if a FormView current mode is Read only so that I can run some codes. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
 protected void FormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Here I want to add codes only if the current view of the Formview is read only (neither insert nor edit modes).
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the FormView is in FormViewMode.ReadOnly.

Check this artice - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
protected void FormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
//Here I want to add codes only if the current view of the Formview is read only (neither insert nor edit modes).
   if (FormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from : [FormView.CurrentMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.currentmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void FormView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   if (FormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
   {
   }
}
```